# Azure Function Isolated mode and ConnectionString set up for CosmosDB

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

I built a .net 8 V4 Azure function app that uses both cosmos db triggers and bindings to read and write data to cosmos db. Locally, the app works fine because I have set up the connection string local.setting.json. However, when I upload the code to Azure, the functions run but it does not communicate with my cosmos db. In the portal, I added the connection string through Environmental variables, and then connection strings, but it did not work. Please one can help to solve this issue.

```
    public CosmosDBFunction(ILogger<CosmosDBFunction> logger,
        IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        _logger = logger;
        _cosmosClient =
        new CosmosClient("AccountEndpoint=<Connection>");
        
    }
    
    [Function(nameof(Function))]
    public static async Task<string> RunOrchestrator(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(CosmosDBFunction));
        logger.LogInformation("----Function Started-----");
    
    
        string pagesToLinks = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(
        nameof(somefunction));
        
        string linksToClins = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(
        nameof(somefunction));
        
        string Blinks = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(
            nameof(somefunction));
    
        logger.LogInformation("----Function Finished-----");
        return "Operation Is Completed";
    }

[Function(nameof(SomeFunction))]
[CosmosDBOutput(databaseName: "X", containerName: "Y",
      Connection = "ConnectionNameSavedInLocal.Setting.json"
     , CreateIfNotExists = true, PartitionKey = "/dd")]
public async Task<string> ScanLinksAndInsertIntoLinksContainer
    ([ActivityTrigger] string name,
    [CosmosDBInput(
    databaseName:"ss",
    containerName:"pt",
    Connection = "ConnectionNameSavedInLocal.Setting.json"
    )]
    List<todo> todos,
    FunctionContext executionContext){}

Host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "extensions": {
      "cosmosDB": {
        "connectionMode": "Direct",
        "userAgentSuffix": "MyDesiredUserAgentStamp"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

local.setting.json

```
    {
      "IsEncrypted": false,
      "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolate

d",
    "CosmosConnection": "AccountEndpoint=https: <ConnectionString>"
  }
  
}
```

In portal I checked the tab Connection String and it looks like this

```
[
  {
    "name": "CosmosConnection",
    "value": "AccountEndpoint= 
             <ConnectionString>",
    "type": "DocDb",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried?

Comment: Is it working in Local environment as you expected?

Comment: Are you able to deploy this function into portal successfully?

Comment: Can you share local.settings.json and host.json?

Comment: @Pavan in my local env it works as expected, but when I run the function in azure it does not

Answer (score 0):

> when I upload the code to Azure, the functions run but it does not communicate with my cosmos db.

- Initially I am also getting same issue. After adding the cosmosdb connection string in appsettings of function app working as expected.
- Make sure the `key must be same in Local and portal appsettings.` and check the binding in integration.
- I have created a function with runtime stack .net 8.0 Isolated and added cosmosdb Input and output binding in the code. The below function executed successfully and when added the Items in cosmosdb container.

```cs
namespace FunctionApp130000
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(Function1));
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello.");
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            // Replace name and input with values relevant for your Durable Functions Activity
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(CosmosTrigger1), "Tokyo"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(CosmosTrigger1), "Seattle"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(CosmosTrigger1), "London"));

            // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
            return outputs;
        }

        [Function(nameof(CosmosTrigger1))]
        [CosmosDBOutput("%sampledb%","%user%", Connection ="CosmosDBConnection", CreateIfNotExists = true)]
        public static async Task<string> CosmosTrigger1([ActivityTrigger] string name, [CosmosDBInput(databaseName: "sampledb",containerName: "user", Connection = "CosmosDBConnection")] List<Todo> todos,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {

            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SayHello");
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
            foreach (var todo in todos)
            {
                // Do something with each todo item
                logger.LogInformation("Processing todo item: {id}, {name}", todo.Id, todo.Name);
            }
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [Function("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1_HttpStart");

            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
                nameof(Function1));

            logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

            // Returns an HTTP 202 response with an instance management payload.
            // See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-http-api#start-orchestration
            return client.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }

    public class Todo
    {
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**local.settings.json:**

```cs
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "CosmosDBConnection": "your-cosmosdb conn-string",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

[image]

I have published the above function into azure portal successfully. check below:
[image]

Check the binding of cosmosdb connection like below:

[image]

- when adding items in cosmosdb trigger getting traces in Invocation details of function. check below:

[image]

Comment: How did you set up the connection string. I still have issue getting it working

Comment: Could you please clearfiy if I really need to add %. Could you please share your host.json

Comment: I am getting this error " Missing Application Settings detected
The following Application Settings are referenced in Function bindings but not configured in the Function App. This can cause execution errors
Function: danfunctionproject/ksContainer, Binding parameter: $return, Application setting: CosmosConnection"

Comment: Can you add cosmos connection string in app settings of function app in portal?

Comment: I have set up the connection string in local.settings.json like as shown in the above solution.

Comment: I have done that, I added the connection, but mine is not working

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on .net 8 V4 isolated Azure function app that uses cosmos db triggers. Works locally every time, when deployed it fails to trigger.

I can see storage exceptions in kudu logs:

```
 "functionAppContentEditingState": "Unknown"
}
2024-03-05T12:08:06  PID[4860] Error       3/5/2024 12:08:06 PM Encountered exception while validating SAS URI System.Exception:Azure storage account must be configured     at DaaS.Storage.AzureStorageService.ValidateStorageConfiguration(String& storageAccount, Exception& exceptionContactingStorage)
2024-03-05T12:08:06  PID[4860] Error       3/5/2024 12:08:06 PM Invalid storage configuration System.Exception:Azure storage account must be configured     at DaaS.Storage.AzureStorageService.ValidateStorageConfiguration(String& storageAccount, Exception& exceptionContactingStorage)
```

I have tested storage connection string locally and works fine, feels like an SDK issue to me.

Comment: Do I really need add a storage connection string to host.json

Comment: Same issue when upgrading to .Net 8 isolated Azure function app cosmos db triggers, works fine locally but not when deployed. Creates container leases so connection string is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. In the Azure portal, there is a tab called Environment Variables, once you click on that you will get two different tabs one called App Settings and Connection Strings. I was saving my connection string inside connection string tab, and that was the reason my app was not working. I added the connection string in the App Setting tabs, the application started working as expected. I am not sure why the connection string is there. This is very confusing and it took a couple of days to figure it out.